# Correlation between two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

what is the correlation/relationship between two matrices

A = \begin{bmatrix}4&0&0&0\\0&3&0&0\\0&0&2&0\end{bmatrix}

B = \begin{bmatrix}1/4&0&0\\0&1/3&0\\0&0&1/2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

where A*B = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

A cannot be an inverse of B because it's not square. So is there a word that describes the relation between this two matrices A and B?

EDIT1: Changed dimensions of A from 4X4 to 3X4

Comment: I think $AB$ is not a $3 \times 3$ matrix

Comment: The dimensions don't agree: A is 4x4, B 4x3 so A*B is not 3x3. Maybe add or remove a line/column of 0? The answer to your question is different depending of those details.

Comment: Once you fix your example, you are probably reaching for the concept of [one-sided inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse#Types).

Comment: Oh sorry, I fixed my example. A is now 3x4 matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be reaching for the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse), usually denoted as $A^+$, which is also defined for rectangular and singular matrices.

In this case:
$$B^+ = \begin{bmatrix}1/4&0&0\\0&1/3&0\\0&0&1/2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}^+
= \begin{bmatrix}4&0&0&0\\0&3&0&0\\0&0&2&0\end{bmatrix}$$
And:
$$B^+\cdot B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$B\cdot B^+=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$